# How to fetch values from CSV valued column

Tags: sql

TABLE1

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
===========================================================
1           2                3           a,b,c
```

Form the above table I need the output to appear as below:

```
Result from query
-----------------
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
===========================================================
1           2                3           a
1           2                3           b
1           2                3           c
```

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, Postgresql, SQL Server or something else?

Comment: This question is way too broad. What have you tried? What tools are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution for your problem, hope it will help...

```
declare @t table
(
ID int identity(1,1),
columnA int,
columnB int,
columnC int,
columnD varchar(20) 
)

insert into @t select 1,2,3,'a,b,c' union all select 4,5,6,'a,b,d' union all select 7,8,9,'a'
--select * from @t

declare @tt table
(
ID int identity(1,1),
columnA int,
columnB int,
columnC int,
columnD varchar(20) 
)

declare @count int
set @count = (select count(*) from @t)
declare @i int = 1
declare @str varchar(20) 

while (@i <= @count)
BEGIN
    set @str = (select columnD from @t where ID = @i)
    while charindex(',' , @str) <> 0 
    begin
        Insert @tt (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD) select columnA, columnB, columnC, left(@str, charindex(',' , @str) - 1) from @t where ID = @i
        SET @str = stuff(@str, 1, charindex(',' , @str), '')
    end
    Insert @tt (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD) select columnA, columnB, columnC, @str from @t where ID = @i

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

select * from @tt
```

Comment: How can that possibly be a "generic" solution when it's expressed in vendor-specific code?